# How to reduce polygon of a wire model

Tags: uv, polycount

i created a wire using curve (grease pencil) and givi it a skin. The problem is when i convert to mesh, it become too dense. What is the best tips to reduce the poly. What should i do before i convert the curve ? and what is the best way to uv unwarp this very high poly ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Maybe Skin is not the best tool to build your mesh, anyway there is a efficient way to simplify a mesh:

- In *Edit* / *Edge Selection* mode, select an edge ring with *ctrl alt right click*.
- Got to *Select* > *Checker Deselect*. Now only one of two edges is selected (or even less if you want, play with the factors at the bottom of the *T* menu, on the left of the 3D view).
- Go to *Select* > *Edge Loops*. Now the edge loops of these edges are selected.
- Delete these edge loops with *X* > *Edge Loops*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The answer of moonbots is correct.

There are also two other ways :

Using a Decimate modifier with un-subdivide method and an even number of iterations (odd numbers will give make the topology diagonal) :

[image]

Or, you can take care of the resolution of the curve before converting into a mesh :

[image]