# Reduce/Remove Sub-edges in Skin Modifier

Tags: modifiers

[image]

When using Skin Modifier it will create sub-edges/intermediate edges (Marked Green on the picture) between two control vertices (Red dots on the picture).
 As far as the shape of the object goes, it is only the Edges produced by control points (Red) I'm interested in, so I have to delete all the unwanted (Green) sub-edges after applying the modifier. Which is fine if the model is simple enough (Just select main edges, invert selection and delete the rest), but with a complex one it gets really time-consuming and at times confusing very fast. 
 Is there a way to make Skin Modifier go without creating those sub-edges at all somehow?

Comment: I don't know if you can avoid edges with the Skin modifier, and I'm not sure it's a perfect tool to create mesh, anyway, you could simplify with these methods: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/114874/how-to-reduce-polygon-of-a-wire-model#114878

Answer (score 2):

You can add a **Decimate** modifier below the Skin modifier, to reduce the number of faces created by the Skin modifier.

Comment: I'd like to add that using the "planar" decimate mode is great with the skin modifier for producing low-poly organic shapes (like handmade trees). It allows you to provide an angle limit and merges planes connected at angles smaller than the limit. Given that the skin modifier produces several parallel planes along edges, setting the angle limit to something arbitrarily small (though greater than zero, like one degree) will eliminate all of these extra planes without deforming the mesh too much at all. Plus, the resulting topology is decent and generally doesn't require remeshing.

Comment: It doesn't unless you want to subdivide. Then it's a horrible mess. We need a skin modifier that just doesn't add the redundant loops.